# What is the metal plating on the back of the A-6 for?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, feature-identification, bomber, a-6

What is the perforated metal plating on the back of the A-6/EA-6A for?

[image]
Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grumman_EA-6A_156983_VMCJ-2_America_30.09.74_edited-2.jpg)

Comment: You mean on the belly to the aft, under the MAR of MARINES?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a speed brake, a plate hinged at the forward edge which can be hydraulically extended to increase aerodynamic drag. It had been used on early models, and the speed brakes were mostly replaced by firmly riveted plates later, because flight test revealed handling problems. The wake of the speed brake disturbed the flow around the horizontal tail especially during approach and landing. They were replaced by wing tip brakes, and from the 304th aircraft on were completely omitted.

See [here](http://www.joebaugher.com/usattack/newa6_1.html) for further details.

Below is a picture of an EA-6B with the wing tip speed brakes (circled red) extended:

[image]
(Source: [navy.mil](http://www.navy.mil/view_image.asp?id=15688))

Comment: Now I'm curious--are those wingtip speed brakes, or a split aileron such as on an A-10 (http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/6/2/3/1681326.jpg)?

Comment: I never realized those aircraft have (at least) 2 types of speed brakes (the one highlighted in the question and the one on the wingtip)

Comment: @Marius, those are wingtip speedbrakes.  They have no other function like a split aileron might.

Comment: P.S. I edited this answer to correctly identify the plane in the photo as an EA-6B. The 2 seat EA-6A pictured in the question had these fuselage speedbrakes because it was an A-6 airframe, the 4 seat EA-6B pictured here did not. FWIW, the first prototype EA-6B was built from an A-6 airframe and had these as well, but production models, (while based on the A-6 and similar in appearance) were actually a very different airframe.  (*Also, I had to check my log book, but I have 21 flights in 160709.  Had a couple landing gear problems with it...*)

Comment: @MichaelHall Thank you, your help is very much appreciated.